# Type hint for an argument that is a value of a class attribute

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylance

In the below code, how can I make the Pylance type error go away? Disclaimer - I understand why the error is there, I just don't know how to make the code work for both the function and the dict at the same time.

Preferably, I would like to achieve this without migrating the class to `Enum` or its attributes to `Literal` (I have tried both, but with limited success - there is always an error in either the dict or the function).

```
class Constants:
    a = 'aaa'
    b = 'bbb'

d = {
    Constants.a: 'a value',
    Constants.b: 'b value',
}

def print_constant(constant: Constants.a): # here Pylance produces the error cited below
    print(constant)

print_constant(Constants.a)
print(d[Constants.a])
```

> Expected type expression but received
> "str"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues (class) Constants

Comment: Err... what is the hint to `print_constant` supposed to mean? Do you intend to only accepts class attributes of `Constants`?

Comment: This seems strange. You're effectively setting the type of `constant` to be the value of an attribute, which isn't a type but an instance of something. You could instead have the value Constants.a = str for instance, which might be better but also doesn't make sense, because the type might change dynamically over time.

Comment: As said abose, you're trying to se the hint to a an attribute, but your attribute isn't a type but in this case a str. If you want the type of `Constants.a` you could use `str` or maybe use `type(Constants.a)`

Comment: @SergeBallesta: As it is now, I meant "accept only 'aaa' string". But yes, it's even better if the type hint was just `Constants`, meaning `aaa` or `bbb`.

Comment: @Ant0ine64: `str` is too broad I think. And `type` is not allowed by Pylance in type hints.

Comment: @PirateNinjas: yes, this is how we define constants (for better or worse) in our project - for example, we want to index a dictionary with a variable to avoid typos. I would like to be able to pass the same constant to a function and make it work on type level (at runtime everything is fine)

Comment: @barciewicz I don't know if this solves your problem or not, but you should use [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/enum.html) for such classes.

Comment: I still have a small problem with your requirements. I now understand that `print_constant` should accept `Constants.a` and not `'foo'` for example. But should it accept `'a' * 3`. If the answer is no, you have a static type question and it can be solved by adding a number of additional type variable defined with `NewType`. If the answer is yes, you want to dynamically check acceptable *values*, and decorators would better fit.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: Thanks for your efforts. I think the answer is no, I don't want to allow `'a' * 3`. I "literally" need the string `aaa` and thought I could reuse the class that already "holds" this string for that. Turns out I would be better off creating a new type as per your suggestion or use an enum (I agree it is the proper thing to do, just a major PITA for our project).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `Literal` type:

```
from typing import Literal


class Constants:
    a = 'aaa'
    b = 'bbb'

d = {
    Constants.a: 'a value',
    Constants.b: 'b value',
}

def print_constant(constant: Literal[Constants.a]): 
    print(constant)

print_constant(Constants.a)
print(d[Constants.a])
```

The docs are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) for more detail. In the likely case I misunderstood your question: sorry!

Comment: Thanks, I think you got my question right and this is what I tried as well . Sadly, this will result in Pylance complaining about this `Literal[Constants.a]` type hint:"Type arguments for "Literal" must be None, a literal value (int, bool, str, or bytes), or an enum value".